# difference between feval and predict in matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to learn a linear regression model in Matlab. So my variables are : `train_fv`, `train_fv_labels`, `test_fv` and `test_fv_labels`. The sizes of the variables are as follows : `333x9`, `333x1`, `167x9` and `167x1`. I want to train the model and then predict the labels on `test_fv` compare them with the actual labels given in `test_fv_labels`.

My matlab code is as follows : I am using a stepwise linear regression to model to get the best fit possible :

```
mdl = stepwiselm(train_fv,train_fv_labels,'PEnter',0.001,'verbose',1)

mdl1 = step(mdl,'upper','quadratic','verbose',1)
```

---

The outputs which I am getting are as follows

```
1. Adding x5, FStat = 83.3108, pValue = 7.06324e-18
2. Adding x1, FStat = 35.6014, pValue = 6.24096e-09
3. Adding x7, FStat = 41.0932, pValue = 5.0338e-10
4. Adding x5:x7, FStat = 33.3157, pValue = 1.81571e-08
5. Adding x1:x5, FStat = 14.1821, pValue = 0.000196729

mdl = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1*x5 + x5*x7

Estimated Coefficients:
                    Estimate         SE         tStat       pValue  
                   __________    __________    _______    __________

    (Intercept)     0.0014532    5.5229e-05     26.312    9.9458e-83
    x1             0.00071972    0.00011402     6.3121    8.9595e-10
    x5             -0.0021179    0.00018102      -11.7    1.1938e-26
    x7              0.0011401    0.00022498     5.0678    6.7473e-07
    x1:x5          -0.0015096    0.00040087    -3.7659    0.00019673
    x5:x7          -0.0049673    0.00077872    -6.3788    6.0915e-10


Number of observations: 333, Error degrees of freedom: 327
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.001
R-squared: 0.442,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.434
F-statistic vs. constant model: 51.9, p-value = 1.65e-39
6. Adding x5^2, FStat = 63.1344, pValue = 3.17359e-14

mdl1 = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1*x5 + x5*x7 + x5^2

Estimated Coefficients:
                    Estimate         SE         tStat       pValue  
                   __________    __________    _______    __________

    (Intercept)     0.0011415    6.4043e-05     17.825    4.3107e-50
    x1             0.00071722    0.00010452     6.8618    3.4339e-11
    x5             -0.0018651    0.00016896    -11.039    2.7782e-24
    x7              0.0011951    0.00020635     5.7915    1.6426e-08
    x1:x5          -0.0019348    0.00037135    -5.2101     3.354e-07
    x5:x7          -0.0045341    0.00071592    -6.3332    7.9578e-10
    x5^2            0.0033789    0.00042525     7.9457    3.1736e-14


Number of observations: 333, Error degrees of freedom: 326
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.000921
R-squared: 0.533,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.524
F-statistic vs. constant model: 61.9, p-value = 5.33e-51
```

---

So it basically means that for regression using mdl model I have this function : **y ~ 1 + x1*x5 + x5*x7** and for mdl1 I have this : **y ~ 1 + x1*x5 + x5*x7 + x5^2**

But when I am trying to predict the values using the test set, I am getting an error. Why is this so ?

```
test_fv_labels = feval(mdl1,test_fv);
```

**Predictor data matrix must have 5 columns.**

But if I use the predict function instead of feval I am not getting an error. Why is this so ?

```
test_fv_labels = predict(mdl1,test_fv);
```

Please kindly tell me where I am going wrong and what is the difference between `predict` and `feval` command in Matlab.

Comment: I might be wrong be I think `predict` is part of the classifier class (as in POO) where `feval` is use to compute the value return by a function, so not related with your classifier object (which is not a function).